# yii2 checkboxList custom class

Tags: yii2

Here is the sample code from Yii2 checkboxList, I want to add custom class for each Item in checkboxList but I don't know how and where can I add that!
Could you please help me please ..

```
$list = [0 => 'PHP', 1 => 'MySQL', 2 => 'Javascript'];
$list2 = [0,2];

echo Html::checkboxList('CuisineId',$list2,$list,array('class' => 'test' ));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to add the same class, you should use `itemOptions` :

```
echo Html::checkboxList('CuisineId', $list2, $list, ['itemOptions'=>['class' => 'test']]);
```

Or if you want a custom class for each item, you should use item callback :

```
echo Html::checkboxList('CuisineId', $list2, $list, ['item'=>function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value){
    return Html::checkbox($name, $checked, [
       'value' => $value,
       'label' => $label,
       'class' => 'any class',
    ]);
}]);
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#checkboxList()-detail

EDIT : add example

Comment: thank you so much for your current replay , but could please give me a sample to do work with this function ? I saw this yesterday in yii2 API documents.. I just want to add different classes to each Item .. I have to write custom function  for each item ? just let me know how to add class to for each Item.. thank you so much for your great replay .

Comment: You only need one function, take a look at my example and docs. And I can't guess what is behind "I just want to add different classes to each Item".

Comment: very nice!  I used $index variable to creating custom class name ! thank you so much ! " 'class' => 'woshiClass'.$index,"

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you only need to change the label options:

```
<?= Html::checkboxList('CuisineId', $list, $items, [
    'itemOptions' => [
        'labelOptions' => [
            'style' => 'font-weight: normal',
            'class' => 'some-custom-class',
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

**Note:** Everything you put inside `itemOptions` will be passed to `Html::checkbox()` as its own options when creating each checkbox. It means you can pass `class`, `style`, `label`, `labelOptions`, etc.

Comment: This working fine for applying styles for checkbox labels. Thank you.